# Intersection of sets as columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, set, intersection

I have a df such as:

```
df=pd.DataFrame.from_items([('i', [set([1,2,3,4]), set([1,2,3,4]), set([1,2,3,4]),set([1,2,3,4])]), ('j', [set([2,3]), set([1]), set([4]),set([3,4])])])
```

so it looks like

```
>>> df
              i       j
0  {1, 2, 3, 4}  {2, 3}
1  {1, 2, 3, 4}     {1}
2  {1, 2, 3, 4}     {4}
3  {1, 2, 3, 4}  {3, 4}
```

I would like to compute df.i.intersection(df.j) and assign that to be column k. That is, I want this:

```
df['k']=[df.i.iloc[t].intersection(df.j.iloc[t]) for t in range(4)]

>>> df.k
0    {2, 3}
1       {1}
2       {4}
3    {3, 4}
Name: k, dtype: object
```

Is there a df.apply() for this? The actual df is millions of rows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Working with `set`s, `list`s and `dict`s in `pandas` is a bit problematic, because best working with scalars:

```
df['k'] = [x[0] & x[1] for x in zip(df['i'], df['j'])]
print (df)
              i       j       k
0  {1, 2, 3, 4}  {2, 3}  {2, 3}
1  {1, 2, 3, 4}     {1}     {1}
2  {1, 2, 3, 4}     {4}     {4}
3  {1, 2, 3, 4}  {3, 4}  {3, 4}
```

---

```
df['k'] = [x[0].intersection(x[1]) for x in zip(df['i'], df['j'])]
print (df)
              i       j       k
0  {1, 2, 3, 4}  {2, 3}  {2, 3}
1  {1, 2, 3, 4}     {1}     {1}
2  {1, 2, 3, 4}     {4}     {4}
3  {1, 2, 3, 4}  {3, 4}  {3, 4}
```

Solution with `apply`:

```
df['k'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['i'].intersection(x['j']), axis=1)
print (df)
              i       j       k
0  {1, 2, 3, 4}  {2, 3}  {2, 3}
1  {1, 2, 3, 4}     {1}     {1}
2  {1, 2, 3, 4}     {4}     {4}
3  {1, 2, 3, 4}  {3, 4}  {3, 4}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can reproduce the set intersection using set differences.
The intersection between A and B is equal to A minus the elements of A that are not in B. (You can symmetrical do it using B).

So, you can use dataframe [sub](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html) method to operate set differences:

```
df['k'] = df['i'].sub(df['i'].sub(df['j']))
# df['k'] = df['j'].sub(df['j'].sub(df['i'])) # equivalent
```

Which gives the expected output:

```
df
Out[11]: 
              i       j       k
0  {1, 2, 3, 4}  {2, 3}  {2, 3}
1  {1, 2, 3, 4}     {1}     {1}
2  {1, 2, 3, 4}     {4}     {4}
3  {1, 2, 3, 4}  {3, 4}  {3, 4}
```