# Extract intersection of 2 columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, set

I have a pandas dataframe in the below format

```
  id      state1      state2
  123     kvnkva      oqinqa
  234     kahfkj      poqrkj
```

I am trying to get the common letters between "state1" and "state2". For that I converted the columns to list and then took the set of them. But when I check the types, they are still of type "object", so I could not perform any set operations on them.

Existing code:

```
 df['list_state1'] = df['state1'].apply(lambda x: list(x))
 df['list_state2'] = df['state2'].apply(lambda x: list(x))
 df['list_state1'] = df['state1'].apply(lambda x: set(x))
 df['list_state2'] = df['list_state2'].apply(lambda x: set(x))
```

After this, I cannot perform the intersection operation as the type of the columns are "object"

```
  expected output:

  id      set_state1      set_state2     set1_intersection_set2
  123     {k,v,n,a}       {o,q,i,n,a}    {n,a}
  234     {k,a,h,f,j}     {p,o,q,r,k,j}  {j}
```

Comment: `df['set1_intersection_set2'] = [x[0] & x[1] for x in zip(df['set_state1'], df['set_state2'])]` as recommended by [jezrael](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45239630/15497888) is likely fastest

Comment: If you don't need the intermediate list state you can pass a string right to the set constructor `df['set_state1'] = df['state1'].apply(lambda x: set(x))`

Comment: df['set1_intersection_set2']=df.apply(lambda x: x['set_state1']&x['set_state2'], axis=1)

Answer (score 0):

```
 x.intersection(y, z)
```

where y and z are the two sets whose intersection is needed. And is stored in x similarly if you want you can make it for a array.
In your case you need to convert the list to set
`set(listOfStudents)` This will convert it to set.

**Note**
This will result in loss of repetitive word otherwise make a explicit function.

Comment: I cannot do the intersection operation on list_state1 and list_state2 as they are of type object.

Comment: Is it not converting to list also, if its textual data then use split to split it into words other wise for normal word by word just list(variable)